# Do I need to do anything to install/run applications in 64 bit?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, docker, 64-bit

I've switched my Raspberry Pi 4 from 32 bit to 64 bit (Raspbian buster) by adding this to `/boot/config.txt`

```
kernel=kernel8.img
arm_64bit=1
```

This seems to work fine. I'm running docker and that has continued to work.

However, as a person coming from the desktop world, I'm used to explicitly running 32 or 64 bit programs.

Do I need to do anything to install and/or run programs in 64 bit mode?

Should reinstall programs like docker or stuff installed with `apt`?

Comment: You can't.  The Raspbian [userland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space#Overview) is still 32-bit; a 64-bit kernel is compatible with that.

Comment: by the way, you only need `arm_64bit=1` if you use the standard `kernel8.img` kernel

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried any of this myself, but this is how I would do it. Make sure to have backups and be ready to roll back if something goes wrong.

First, add the [Debian repo](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) to your sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Then add the `arm64` architecture and update the package list

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64 
sudo apt update
# don't upgrade
```

Note that it's not recommended to `upgrade` while you have Debian repos as sources. I got weird issues after such an upgrade, and since quite a few  Raspbian packages got replaced by Debian counterparts, I wasn't inclined to track down those issues.

Finally, install an `arm64` program:

```
sudo apt install firefox:arm64
```

This will pull a lot of dependencies including the most basic ones like `libc`, since the rest of your system is 32-bit. Then you should be able to run your 64-bit software alongside the rest of your 32-bit userland. If you have the same program in 32 and 64 bits, you'll have to find out where the 64-bit version is installed, my guess would be `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/`, `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/`, `/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu/`, or something along these lines.

Note: you may already know, but Ubuntu [supports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) RPi and is known to run 64-bit binaries.